C++26 Reflection and Loops over enums
Does C++26 reflection proposal include a way to loop through enums?

I would recommend to ask your question a bit differently. Users here can't know what will be included in C++26. But they can tell you whether current reflection proposals considered for C++26 would allow you to do this and how it would look.

I did update. Thanks for the advice

You can read the proposal yourself https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p2996r4.html#enum-to-string

If you know the proposal number, you can easily get a redirect to the latest published version of the paper https://wg21.link/p2996

Language proposal P2996 specifies std::meta::enumerators_of(), enabling us to write something like this when it's adopted:
  template for (constexpr auto e: std::meta::enumerators_of(^E)) {
      auto const v = [:e:];
      // ...
  }

Or more concisely, if range splicers are available:
  for (auto v: [: ...std::meta::enumerators_of(^E) :]) {
      // ...
  }

Although P2996 targets C++26, it doesn't include range splicers as part of the proposal.  They may be adopted in a later standard.
